# How to use URL Rewrite before HTTP Redirect on IIS

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

So I have a website running on IIS on an address like this: `myserver.com/mysite`.
From here I made a rule to redirect the site to: `myserver.com/mysite/path/to/file`.

I did this using the HTTP redirection module to make a 302 redirect to `path/to/file` and that works fine.

The problem is that if I dont put the trailing slash `/` at the end of `mysite` I get a 404 error, so I used the built-in template `AddTrailingSlashRule` in the URL Rewrite module.

So if I disable the redirect, the trailing slash gets added at the end of the website just fine, but once I enable the HTTP redirect, it sends me to `myserver.com/path/to/file/` and obviously that doesn't work, because I get the redirect first and then the rewrite.

Is there a way to change the "order" of the modules? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can complete all tasks using the rewrite module so stop using the redirect module.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I could also redirect using the url rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having this problem in the future, I ended up disabling the HTTP redirect and made a new rule using the URL Rewrite module.

It simply matches the `^$` regex and then redirects to `path/to/file`.

That rule goes after the trailing slash one so with or without the slash, it gets added and only then it gets redirected.